# How to validate the XML file converted to json file

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

I am new to programming.We have a requirement where the XML is converted and stored as JSON in Mongodb.
Now My question  i want to validate the XML with JSON to make sure the converted file is not cropped.

In our requirement we are using C#,.Net.

Please let me know how the data validation can be done.

Comment: It sounds like you want to validate JSON. Is that correct? If so then it doesn't matter whether the JSON came from XML or not. It's confusing when you say 'validate the XML with JSON'. You can validate XML, you can validate JSON, or you can do both. You can convert XML to JSON and then validate the JSON. But you can't 'validate XML with JSON.;

Comment: I think he wants to compare the contents of the xml and json to make sure that there are no differences.

Comment: I guess the easiest way to accomplish that is the following: JSON (mongodb) -> Object -> Serialize to XML -> Compare with old XML. I'm sure there are plenty of code snippets which can compare XML documents (content wise).

Comment: Sorry to confuse you guys i need to validate the contents of the XML and Json to make sure that there are no differences

Answer (score 0):

As your *content* does not change and only your *serialization format* does - hashes are often used in these kinds of scenarios. CRC-32, MD5, or SHA are some of the mostly used hashing algorithms. You can have one hash per document and/or one for all documents. Generate a hash from the document contents in your XML file and include the hash in the XML document, once a document is converted to JSON generate a hash from its content and compare it with the hash you got with the XML for that document; if they match you are good if not there is some kind of convertion error.